# How to simulate app termination in Xcode8?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am a beginner. at the moment, I am using Xcode8, since most of tutorial I follow and some app I have built is in Xcode8. so I still using Xcode8 at this time. because I am worried it will cause a problem when my previous app is opened in the Xcode9.

I want to test `applicationWillTerminate` method in app delegate, that will be triggered when the app is terminated by the operating system for example. the tutorial i follow along is using Xcode9, and it is easy to simulate termination in Xcode9. but i don't know how in Xcode8.

so, how o simulate app termination in Xcode8?

Comment: Did you tested `applicationWillTerminate` for xcode 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to test your applicationWillTerminate methods, set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to YES in your .plist and then switch apps or press the home button. Make sure you set the key to a Boolean, not the string "YES".

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what i am looking for, UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend same as 'Application does not run in background' now in the info.plist